# Implement Firebase Authentication in my AngularJS website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am building an AngularJS website for school. I need to implement account functionality using firebase auth. I have little experience with Javascript, so AngularJS in and of itself is a challenge for me to use, as is trying to figure out how to implement firebase. The project itself is built from this angularjs seed: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed. Would someone be able to explain how I would implement firebase authentication into the index.html file? I imagine some code will have to go in app.js, and form data will be in index.html. But beyond that, I am rather lost. Essentially, what code goes where, is what I am asking. If you are able to help, THANK YOU.

Comment: Keep in mind that AngularJS is different from Angular. The former goes to I think version 1.7 while the latter is technically version 2+ and completely different in how you write and implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has his own library that you can use to implement it. You have examples in [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui).

Comment: I did see that, but the code snippets do not indicate in what file I should place them, which is what I am asking for because I have little experience with Javascript and I do not know where to put the code the docs show me.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/firebase-authentication-using-angularjs